# put array contents into csv column

Tags: php, arrays, csv, export-to-csv

I have a date array:

```
$date = array();
```

and a name array:

```
$name = array();
```

and I created a bidimensional array, or array in array

```
$allinone = array($date,$names);
```

and with this php I put them into csv:

```
$fp = fopen('download.csv', 'w');
foreach ($allinone as $key => $values) {
    fputcsv($fp, $values);
}
fclose($fp);
```

with this it looks like:

[image]

but I want to achieve to transpose them to column, like this:[image]

How to make this to work? I tried array_combine and merge but does not helped me.

Thank you your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you can just iterate over one array, controlling it's key and output it's value along with value of the **same key** of the second array:

```
$fp = fopen('download.csv', 'w');
foreach ($date as $key => $value) {
    fputcsv($fp, array($value, $name[$key]));
}
fclose($fp);
```

If source arrays have different keys, you can reindex both arrays to numeric keys with `array_values`:

```
$date = array_values($date);
$name = array_values($name);

$fp = fopen('download.csv', 'w');
foreach ($date as $key => $value) {
    fputcsv($fp, array($value, $name[$key]));
}
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: That is what I want, thank you, the arrays have same keys :)

Comment: How are your original two arrays built? Are you sure that the indexes are the same? Could you build one array  instead of three?

Comment: yes sure, example: I have an array with day, month, and year, and I build a date array with joining the values on same indexes